# How to read lines from file starting from arbitrary newline in Python

Tags: python, file, newline

I have a file formatted in a way that lines are separated with a new line, like the following

```
1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3
```

I would like to read the lines separately starting, for example, from the second one and save them in an array. I think I can manage the last part, but I can't figure out how to read starting from the nth newline of the file. 
Any idea on how can I do it?
Thanks.
Best regards.

Comment: show what code you know.  If you are using readlines, you can count to the point at which you want to save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
n1, n2 = 0, 2

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    print '\n'.join(f.read().split('\n')[n1:n2+1])
```

This would produce (as per the contents in the file you've posted) the output like this:

```
1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3
```

**EDIT 1**:

@mic-tiz According to the comment you posted below, I understand that you wish to have all the numbers in your text file into a single array.

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    array = [i for i in f.read() if not i == ' ']
```

This code as you mentioned, would produce a list `array`

```
array = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '\n', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '\n', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3']
```

Then, you can print the elements by splitting it on the occurrence of `\n` character.

**EDIT 2**:
You can save those numbers in a dictionary using the code below

```
d = {}
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    array = f.read().split('\n')

for i in range(len(array)):
    d['l%r'%i] = [int(j) for j in array[i] if not j == ' ']
```

This will produce `d = {'l2': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'l0': [1, 1, 1, 1], 'l1': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]}`

Comment: This methods can print the lines I wont, but now I'm not sure how to put each number of the line in a different position of an array like [1, 1, 1, 1].

Comment: Ok, I think I cracked the last part like this I = []

with open('I_t.dat') as f:
    i = '\n'.join(f.read().split('\n')[n1:n2])
    
for j in i:
    if j == '\t':
        continue
    else:
        I.append(float(j))

Comment: Just one problem. Now I have a file formatted as 1\t1\t1\t, and if I try to remove the \t with the method mentioned before I end with an array of numbers from 0 to 9, but my file contains also greater numbers and I don't get the problem.

Comment: @mictiz Which method did you try? It'd be helpful if you could update your question with your current code. If it's the third one, replace that `' '` (in line number 5) with `'\t'` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I did this 
'with open('I_t.dat') as f:
    i = '\n'.join(f.read().split('\n')[n1:n2])
a = i.split('\t')'
and I get the right values adding the last line, but like this: ['1','1','1'] and I need them like this [1,1,1]
thanks

Comment: @mictiz Isn't that supposed to be a text file? Okay, if you're getting a list as `l = ['1','1','1']` use `l = [eval(i) for i in l]`

Comment: No I'm sorry maybe I wasn't clear, it's a file of numbers.Thanks, that should work, but I get the error File "<string>", line unknown
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Answer (score 2):

As files are iterable in python you could call [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next) on it to skip the first line, for example:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as data:
    next(data)
    for line in data:
        print line.split()
```

Would yield:

```
['2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2']
['3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3']
```

References:

- [next](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next)
- [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: You should add to your example code how to start from nth line instead of skipping a single line. Might answer original question better.

Comment: @wrkyle I'd rather leave that up to the OP, generalizing to skip n lines shouldn't be too much of a leap :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertool.islice` for this, eg:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('filename') as fin:
    wanted = islice(fin, 1, None) # change 1 to lines to skip
    data = [line.split() for line in wanted]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lines = open('test.txt', 'r').readlines()

# n is your desired line
for lineno in range(n-1, len(lines)):
    print list(lines[lineno].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot jump directly to a specific line. You have to read the first n lines:

```
n = 1
with open('data.txt', 'r') as data:
    for idx, _ in enumerate(data):
        if idx == n:
            break
    for line in data:
        print line.split()
```